Schedule a Job at later time in Quarkus JBeret
I use Quarkus implementation of JBeret and want to schedule a job i.e later in the day.
So I use Scheduler with a SchedulerExpression. But the job is processed immediately after scheduling and not waiting until schedule time is reached. I searched in tests, but all tests use initialDelay, there is no test using ScheduledExpression.
`       Properties properties = prepareJobCreation(currentJobName);
properties.setProperty(BatchParamName.FIRST_DAY_PREV_YEAR, firstDayPrevYear);
    ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression();
    scheduleExpression.dayOfMonth(17);
    scheduleExpression.month(8);
    scheduleExpression.year(2024);
    scheduleExpression.hour(18);
    scheduleExpression.minute(1);
    scheduleExpression.second(0);
    final JobScheduleConfig scheduleConfig = JobScheduleConfigBuilder.newInstance()
            .jobName("jobname")
            .scheduleExpression(scheduleExpression)
            .jobParameters(properties)
            .build();

    jobScheduler.schedule(scheduleConfig);

`
When running this code on September, 17th, 2024 17:50 job was processed at 17:50 and at 18:01 nothing occured.
I also tried to put 9 to month (instead of 8 as usually in Java) bot no success as well.
Is there a possibility in Quarkus JBeret to do this? Or am I doing wrong?

My guess is that ScheduleExpression is part of ejb api, which creates a cron schedule to be executed by ejb container, which may not be present in your quarkus.

Thank you for your guess, you are right, Quarkus did not implement this. If you want to schedule a job for a later time you have to use initialDelay and set number of minutes to the desired timestamp
